# microsoft.sqlserver.dmf needs to be installed in the GAC

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, gac

Today I created a console application that generates an SQL script and uploads it via sftp. All works great when on my local computer. The issue is when I try and install it on the server i get an error that says:

[image: Error]

Can anyone help me to fix this issue? How can I install the application on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need to install the SQL Server client tools SDK on the target machine...

Comment: I was going to install it today and when i looked at it is said it was already installed. Could it be that I am running sql server 2008 on the server?

Comment: Ok I got it, I needed to install the 2012 feature pack. http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=29065